# How can i hide my bottom nav bar on button pressed, flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I have a widget `CustomerView` widget that holds a `bottomNavigationBar` button, when this button is clicked i want to hide my bottom navigation bar and when the button is clicked again, i want to show the bottom navigation bar.

This is how the UI looks with the button and my bottom nav bar:

[image: Button and Bottom Nav Bar]

Here is the controller for the Navigation bar:

```
class RootController extends GetxController {
  final currentIndex = 0.obs;
  final notificationsCount = 0.obs;
  final customPages = <CustomPage>[].obs;
  NotificationRepository _notificationRepository;
  CustomPageRepository _customPageRepository;
  RootController() {
    _notificationRepository = new NotificationRepository();
    _customPageRepository = new CustomPageRepository();
  }

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    await getCustomPages();
    if (Get.arguments != null && Get.arguments is int) {
      changePageInRoot(Get.arguments as int);
    } else {
      changePageInRoot(0);
    }
    super.onInit();
  }

  List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeView(),
    JobsView(),
    CustomersView(),
    MessagesView(),
    AccountView(),
  ];

  Widget get currentPage => pages[currentIndex.value];

  /**
   * change page in route
   * */
  void changePageInRoot(int _index) {
    currentIndex.value = _index;
  }
  
  void changePageOutRoot(int _index) {
    currentIndex.value = _index;
    Get.offNamedUntil(Routes.ROOT, (Route route) {
      if (route.settings.name == Routes.ROOT) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }, arguments: _index);
  }

  Future<void> changePage(int _index) async {
    if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.ROOT) {
      changePageInRoot(_index);
    } else {
      changePageOutRoot(_index);
    }
    await refreshPage(_index);
  }

  Future<void> refreshPage(int _index) async {
    switch (_index) {
      case 0:
        {
          await Get.find<HomeController>().refreshHome();
          break;
        }
      case 2:
        {
          await Get.find<MessagesController>().refreshMessages();
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  void getNotificationsCount() async {
    notificationsCount.value = await _notificationRepository.getCount();
  }

  Future<void> getCustomPages() async {
    customPages.assignAll(await _customPageRepository.all());
  }
}
```

This is the View code for the Navigation Bar:

```
class RootView extends GetView<RootController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Obx(() {
      return Scaffold(
        drawer: MainDrawerWidget(),
        
        body: controller.currentPage,
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
          
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
          itemColor: Color(0xffB0BEC1),
          currentIndex: controller.currentIndex.value,
          onChange: (index) {
            controller.changePage(index);
          },
          children: [
            CustomBottomNavigationItem(
              icon: Icons.home_filled,
              label: "Home".tr,
            ),
            CustomBottomNavigationItem(
              icon: Icons.book_outlined,
              label: "Jobs".tr,
            ),
            
            CustomBottomNavigationItem(
              
              icon: Icons.people_outlined,
              label: "Customers".tr,
            ),
            CustomBottomNavigationItem(
              icon: Icons.chat_outlined,
              label: "Messages".tr,
            ),
            CustomBottomNavigationItem(
              icon: Icons.person_outline_rounded,
              label: "Account".tr,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the `CustomBottomNavigationBar` widget itself

```
const Color PRIMARY_COLOR = Colors.blueAccent;
const Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color(0xffE2E7F2);

class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color itemColor;
  final List<CustomBottomNavigationItem> children;
  final Function(int) onChange;
  final int currentIndex;

  CustomBottomNavigationBar(
      {this.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR,
      this.itemColor = PRIMARY_COLOR,
      this.currentIndex = 0,
      @required this.children,
      this.onChange});

  @override
  _CustomBottomNavigationBarState createState() =>
      _CustomBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> {
  
  void _changeIndex(int index) {
    if (widget.onChange != null) {
      widget.onChange(index);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.11,
      color: widget.backgroundColor,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: widget.children.map((item) {
          var icon = item.icon;
          var label = item.label;
          int index = widget.children.indexOf(item);
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _changeIndex(index);
            },
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  icon,
                  size: 24,
                  color: widget.currentIndex == index
                      ? Color(0xff34495E)
                      : Color(0xff7F8D90),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Text(
                    label ?? '',
                    // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                        color: widget.currentIndex == index
                            ? Color(0xff34495E)
                            : Color(0xff7F8D90)),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomBottomNavigationItem {
  final IconData icon;
  final String label;
  final Color color;

  CustomBottomNavigationItem(
      {@required this.icon, @required this.label, this.color});
}
```

How do i achieve this?

I have tried checking articles on here, but all of them seem to only tell me how to hide bottom navigation bar on scroll.

Thank you!

Comment: you can define a bool in the controller and use that bool to show or hide the button nav on the button click change bool value and place that bottom bar in the visibility widget.

Comment: @ManishDayma Thank you for the response, can you explain better or with an example as i got confused along the line.

Comment: Have a look at the answer and ask further questions if not understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a bool in controller to control the visibility

```
class RootController extends GetxController {
 var isBottomBarVisible = true.obs;
 
  void toggleBottomBar() {
       isBottomBarVisible.value = !isBottomBarVisible.value;
  }
```

Then Wrap your bottom bar with visibility widget

```
bottomNavigationBar: Visibility(
  visible: controller.isBottomBarVisible.value,
  child: CustomBottomNavigationBar(),
)
```

Done. Just change this bool **isBottomBarVisible** to see the result.

Comment: This is closer to what i'm looking for!! It works when i change to ` visible: controller.isBottomBarVisible.isFalse` but i want this to be handled with the button in another widget as shown in the image i gave. and after i press that button again, i want it to change visibility back to true .

Comment: I get an error in the controller when i added the method : "isBottomBarVisible can't be used as a setter cos it's final, try finding a different setter". I also get an error in the view when i added the `visible: controller.isBottomBarVisible` line : "the argument type 'RxBool' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' " . :(

Comment: still get an error for this method `void toggleBottomBar() {
       isBottomBarVisible = !isBottomBarVisible;
  }` : "a negation operand must have a static type of 'bool', try changing the operand to the '!' operator."

Comment: Is that working fine now ?

Comment: Yes it is!! Thank you sir... this was a detailed explanation and i have learnt new stuff today!  Can we connect?

Comment: my profile has a link to my GitHub have a look at that.

Comment: your github page gives a "404-not found" error :), are you on linkedin?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/manishdayma

Answer (score 0):

Just add the isClicked check on the bottomNavigationBar property and as it accepts any Widget class, so if you want to hide it, it will hide and display a SizedBox of height 0 when you want to hide it.

```
 class RootView extends GetView<RootController> {
 bool isClicked = false; 
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Obx(() {
    return Scaffold(
     drawer: MainDrawerWidget(),
     body: controller.currentPage,
     bottomNavigationBar:isClicked? CustomBottomNavigationBar(
      
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
      itemColor: Color(0xffB0BEC1),
      currentIndex: controller.currentIndex.value,
      onChange: (index) {
        controller.changePage(index);
      },
      children: [
        CustomBottomNavigationItem(
          icon: Icons.home_filled,
          label: "Home".tr,
        ),
        CustomBottomNavigationItem(
          icon: Icons.book_outlined,
          label: "Jobs".tr,
        ),
        
        CustomBottomNavigationItem(
          
          icon: Icons.people_outlined,
          label: "Customers".tr,
        ),
        CustomBottomNavigationItem(
          icon: Icons.chat_outlined,
          label: "Messages".tr,
        ),
        CustomBottomNavigationItem(
          icon: Icons.person_outline_rounded,
          label: "Account".tr,
        ),
      ],
    ) : SizedBox(),
  );
});
```

}
}

Comment: Thank you sir for this response, but i don't think you understand what i want, i want to hide the bottom navigation bar only when i click a button in another widget ( button is shown in the UI image ) , and i want to show the bottom nav bar when i click same button again.